# Laravel Spark 4.0: Unsupported driver [mongodb]

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.4, laravel-spark, jenssegers-mongodb

I tried installing package   [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to add mongodb 
 support to my existing Laravel Spark app that runs with MySQL database.

My code with error:

```
DB::connection('mongodb')
                ->collection('sample_data')
                ->insert([
                        'custom_id' => 1,
                        'data' => $myData,
                    ]);
```

I already tested `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` package with Laravel 5.4 and no problem at all.

Anyone encountered similar using Laravel Spark 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Need to move

```
Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
```

before

```
Laravel\Spark\Providers\SparkServiceProvider::class,
```